# Is independence inherited by modifications when the original process is iid

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, independence

Consider a sequence of iid random variables $(X_{n})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ as well as a modification of the original sequence, namely $(Y_{n})_{n \in \mathbb N}$.

Is independence inherited by $(Y_{n})_{n \in \mathbb N}$?

Clearly $(Y_{n})_{n \in \mathbb N}$ are identically distributed. I do not think that $(Y_{n})_{n \in \mathbb N}$ are independent but would like some reassurance or intuition as to why I am correct or incorrect.

My thoughts:

For any $n\in \mathbb N$ there exists some null set $N_{n}$ such that  $Y_{n}=X_{n}$ on $\Omega\setminus N_{n}$.

for $m \neq n$ we know that $\sigma (X_{m})\perp \!\!\! \perp \sigma(X_{n})$ thus to say that $\sigma (Y_{m})\perp \!\!\! \perp \sigma(Y_{n})$ we need that $\sigma (Y_{m})\subseteq \sigma(X_{m})$ and $\sigma (Y_{n})\subseteq \sigma(X_{n})$. The mere fact that they are modifications of each other does not mean that sigma algebras contain one another.

Comment: What is a modification of the original sequence?

Comment: $(Y_{n})_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is a modification iff $P(X_{n}=Y_{n})=1$ for all $n$